# ArcGIS 10.2 Modelbuilder Spatial Join is not generating an output

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder, spatial-join

I have a model that runs spatial joins in a lines to points relationship and then adds and calculates fields to that join. The parameters are one to one and intersecting at 1 foot.  The search distance is so low because the points are already snapped to the lines. During my initial test run, the spatial joins worked fine in the model, but I realize that the difference here is that I was working in a local environment. This time, I am required to run the model using inputs from a network drive. Could this be my issue? Or am I missing something really obvious here? The spatial join is on a dataset of at least 20,000 lines, so it should be taking around 20 minutes to complete.  IN this new model, the operation is done in mere seconds, so I know its not doing what its suppose to be doing.

Comment: Is it creating any output? Do the input layers have common coordinate systems?

Comment: I have verified the projections and the GCS. Also, there is no output whatsoever being created even though the workspace and layer name are all correct. Yet, the model is saying that it ran successfully.  Here is the weird thing: When running the model in model builder in edit mode, the outputs generate and are added to ArcMap.

Comment: So you say when model builder is open the model runs as expected? Was is the alternative you are running this model, as a tool from toolbox or from a script? Are you putting the same datasets in to the model when you run it this other way? Are there selections or does model logic expect a selection to exist?

Comment: Yes when in edit mode, the operation will write to the output location and add the result to the map display. But, when running as a tool with input parameters (like every other tool in the ArcToolbox) it does not write a new dataset to an output location. This model is part 2 of a custom toolbox and depends on the results from the first model. However, after checking and rechecking, changing the input feature class (as a parameter) does not affect the results of the model (when performed in edit mode).

Answer (score 2):

This question has been resolved. In order to generate an output for spatial join, the output dataset has to be set as a parameter and the workspace of the model tool must match the workspace of the map document. If they match, the output is generated and added to ArcMap TOC upon completion of the model.